# How would I keep a count value in my function?

Tags: java, counting

I need to make a program that simulates a game of craps. But what I'm having problems with is keeping count of the number of times the player wins or loses. I think it's because since the count isn't in the main method it sets itself back to 0 but I don't know how to fix it. Here's the code to run the program

```
public class Craps {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to my Craps game");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press 'OK' to roll the dice");

    //Calls the craps function
    playCraps();
    
    //Asks user if they want to play again
    String playAgain = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to play again?\n(enter 'y' for yes)");

    while(playAgain.equals("y")){
      playCraps();
    }

  }


  static void playCraps(){
    Die die1 = new Die(6);
    Die die2 = new Die(6);

    boolean firstTry = false;
    
    //Generates the die
    int roll1 = die1.roll();
    int roll2 = die2.roll();

    int sum = roll1 + roll2;

    //counts the amount of times the player wins or loses
    int winCount = 0;
    int loseCount = 0;

    //Shows the rolls and the sum
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You rolled a " + roll1 + " and a " + roll2 + ".\n\nThe sum is " + sum);

    //If the player doesn't win or lose on their first try,
    //it keeps rolling until they win or lose
    if(sum == 7 || sum == 11){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!!!");
      winCount++;
      firstTry = true;
    }else if(sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose.");
      loseCount = loseCount + 1;
      firstTry = true;
    }else{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
      "You must keep rolling. If you roll a " + sum + " again, you win. If you roll a 7 before that, you lose.");
        
      while(firstTry == false){
        int secRoll1 = die1.roll();
        int secRoll2 = die2.roll();
        int secSum = secRoll1 + secRoll2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You rolled a " + secRoll1 + " and a " + secRoll2 + ".\n\nThe sum is " + secSum);
        
        if(secSum == sum){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You matched!!!");
          winCount++;
          break;
        }

        if(secSum == 7){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm sorry, you rolled a 7.");
          loseCount++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    //Shows the user how many times they win or lose
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your current score..." + "\nwins: " + winCount + "\nlosses: " + loseCount);
  }

}
```

```
public class Die 
{
    private int sides;
    private int total;
    private int rolls;

    //The following method is called a 'Constructor'
    //it runs when a new 'Die' is created
    
    public Die(int numSides) 
    {
        sides=numSides;
        total=0;
        rolls=0;
    }
    
    
    
    //gets a die roll
    public int roll()
    {
        int result = (int)(Math.random()*sides+1);
            
        total = total+result;
        rolls++;
            
        return result;
    }
    
    // The following methods return information about the die
    
    public int getSides()
    {
        return sides;
    }
    
    public int getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }
    
    public int getRolls()
    {
        return rolls;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Yep... move your counts and set them as class variables - they should not be local to the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int winCount = 0;
int loseCount = 0;
```

Your variables are declared in the playCraps method, so they are 'lost' and 're-created' each time you exit/call the method (as you have guessed). To fix this issue, you have to make them global:

```
public class Craps{
  public static int winCount=0;
  public static int loseCount=0;

  <your other methods like main and play>
}
```

This will make them accessible from anywhere, and therefore their value will increase as the user keeps playing.

Answer (score 2):

You exactly mentioned the reason, the scope for assigning the counts is the same in each call, So you simply start the count again from the beginning.

In your **Craps** class itself, define the same tracker counts as private fields and use them instead, So you just need to move them to class scope; something like this.

```java
public class Craps {
   private static int winCount = 0;
   private static int loseCount = 0;
}
```

For more information about this within simple tutorial, try to read this
[Variables Scope in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/#:%7E:text=Scope%20of%20a%20variable%20is,independent%20of%20function%20call%20stack.)

Answer (score 1):

Everytime your `playCraps();` function is called, your counts are reset.

You could change to

```
//counts the amount of times the player wins or loses
 static int winCount = 0;
 static int loseCount = 0;
```

Being static will prevent the counts from being reset each time. **However, if you plan to add other players that will not work.**

In this case, you could change your structure so that you have a class member than is incremented for each players.

Comment: It's a possible approach, but in most cases not a very good one.

Comment: Totally agree with you @klutt